# Audio Visualizer with JavaScript/HTML5 not Visualizing

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio, visualization

Hello: I have a questions regarding my implementation of the visualization of audio (songs):

Currently, the HTML file and CSS file display what I want (a black box with a blue/cyan box underneath, as well as the `audio.controls` displaying), and the audio plays as it should. However, the script.js JavaScript files do not work to visualize the audio that is playing. Is this an issue with the ***linking*** of the JavaScript file, my use of the ***Web Audio API***, or something else? Here is my code:

***HTML*** - index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
<title>Audio Visualizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mp3_player">
        <div id="audio_box"></div>
        <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS*** style.css

```
 #mp3_player {
        width: 500px;
        height: 60px;
        background: #000;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
    <code>#mp3_player > div > audio{
        width: 500px;
        background: #000;
        float: left;
    }
    <code>#mp3_player > canvas{
        width: 500px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #002D3C;
        float: left;
    }
```

***JavaScript*** script.js

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'gypsyheart.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;<code>
var canvas, ctx, source, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.CreateAnalyser();
    canvas=  document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
function frameLooper(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF';
            bars = 100;
            for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
                bar_x = i*3;
                bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
                bar_width = 2
                ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
            }
}
```

***FILE TREE***

```
_folder includes (with no sub-folders):_
gypsyheart.mp3
index.html
style.css
script.js
```

Thank you for helping me out. All comments and suggestions are appreciated. If you have a different idea on how to approach this problem of visualizing (simply) music, I'd love to hear it, and am open to different methods of solving this problem! Apologies for any formatting errors here (first time using Stack Overflow)!

-Quin

Comment: NOTE: I fixed the capital C on line 11 of the JavaScript to `context.createAnalyser();` but still to no avail.

Comment: NOTE v2: How does one link/reference the Web Audio API to the JavaScript so that the computer understands it is reading the Web Audio API?

Comment: [something working to start from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443535/128511)